# Be $f:Ω \to \mathbb {R} $ .Prove that for every closed set $C ⊂ \mathbb {R}$, $\exists K ⊂ \mathbb {R}$ closed such that $f^{−1}(C) = K ∩ Ω$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Somebody could help me proving this statment?

Be $Ω  \subset\mathbb {R}$ an open set and $f:Ω \to \mathbb {R}
$ such that for every open set $A ⊂  \mathbb {R}$  $f^{−1}(A)$ is open

Prove that for every closed set $C ⊂  \mathbb {R}$, $\exists K ⊂ \mathbb {R}$ closed such that $f^{−1}(C) = K ∩ Ω$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $C  \subseteq \Bbb R$ is closed, $C^\complement$ is open in $\Bbb R$ so by assumption $O’=f^{-1}[C^\complement]$ is open in $\Bbb R$ and so take $K=O’^\complement$ which is closed and note that $f^{-1}[C]= \Omega \cap K$.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the continuity of function $f$. The fact that for every open set $f^{-1}$ is open implies the continuity. The continuity implies that for every closed set $C$, $f^{-1}(C)$ is a closed set.